# WPF Style Binding to Base Style

Tags: wpf, inheritance, binding, styles

i have a base style and a style in wpf.

the base style is:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DDFFDD" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="behaviors:OCCInteraction.Triggers" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=validationTrigger}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFDDDD"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the the specific style is:

```
<Style x:Key="EditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BaseTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Padding="0" Margin="0">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Margin="0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="test" />
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=WarningImage}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self,AncestorLevel=2}}" />

                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now i want to add the Validation Error Text to a textblock next to the image. But the Same Binding Path doesn't work. I've tried diferent bindings, but I can't figure out how to access the same binding like on the base style.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it without the AncestorLevel? You should be the same object.

Comment: Hey, yes I tried the same as in be Base style, several relativ source configurations etc. Normally I would work with the Ancestor Level, but this seems not to work with styles :(

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Mode=Self` and `AncestorLevel` properties. Just use `Mode=Self`.

Ancestor level is used when you try to reach parent of that control in visual tree.

Comment: Hey, yes i know about the functionality of 'AncestorLevel'. This piece of code was just one state of my "just trying".